# spring boot and jpa: simple oneToMany join doesn't return any data

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

A customer can have multiple accounts. An account belongs to only one customer.  A customer can have no accounts, but an account always has a customer.

I cant find how to make this work in spring boot 3.1.5 (I think) with JPA.  I've compared mine to published examples (e.g https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)  and I can't find the difference.

Its creating the right tables, and inserting works, but reading the accounts for a customer never finds the customers accounts.

Im using H2 DB which auto-generates the schema each time I restart (which is the desired method during the development phase)

Here is the Customer Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "customer_seq", sequenceName = "customer_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "customer_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 256, nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 16, message = "Password must be between 8 and 16 characters long")
    private String password;

    // Where do you tell it the table to map to (i.e. Account) and the FK column in that table (i.e. customer_id)?
    // If it can "guess" the table by the "Account" object name, why cant it guess the FK column name is "customer_id"?
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Account> accounts;

    public Customer(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) // not needed any more?
    private Date dob;  // or use sql.Date?

// other fields omitted for brevity.

}
```

Here is the Account Entity with various combinations I have tried:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account  {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "account_seq", sequenceName = "account_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "account_seq")
    private Long id;

    BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(0);

    // How can you tell it that "customer" is the FK to the ID of the Customer Table?  It should be able to guess that.
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)

// runs, but doesnt find any accounts for any customer.
//    @OneToOne(optional = false)

// runs, but doesnt find any accounts for any customer.
//    @JoinColumn

//  This one runs, but never finds accounts for any customer.
//    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)

//  Fails with: Column 'id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.ohds.bomj.entity.Account'
//    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)

//  This one also runs, but never finds accounts for any customer.
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false) // doesnt run

//  This one fails with: references a column named 'customer_id' but the target entity 'com.ohds.bomj.entity.Customer' has no property which maps to this column
//    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    Customer customer;

    public Account(Customer c) {
        this.customer = c;
    }
}
```

If you look at the below screen shot of the H2 console, we can see its created the expected "CUSTOMER_ID" column on Account, and correctly populated it with the customer with ID of 100.

However, the FK doesnt look like its pointing to customer.id FK should be pointing to the Id in the customer table.

[image: Account table]

Below we can see the customers in the customer table, along with one with ID of 100.

[image]

To try to read customers accounts, Im using the following controller:

```
@RestController
class CustomerController {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class);

    private final CustomerRepository repository;

    CustomerController(CustomerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/customers")
    List<Customer> all() {

        List<Customer> customers = repository.findAll();

        // for each customer, get the accounts
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            log.info("customer: " + customer);
            log.info("accounts: " + customer.getAccounts());
        }

        return customers;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer(id=1, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=user@haha.com, password=haha123, phone=null, accounts=[], dob=null)
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: []
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer(id=2, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=me@foo.com, password=foobarr123, phone=null, accounts=[], dob=null)
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: []
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer(id=100, firstName=bob, lastName=null, email=haha@blabla, password=12345678, phone=null, accounts=[], dob=1969-07-05)
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: []
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer(id=101, firstName=null, lastName=null, email=another@one.com, password=12345678, phone=null, accounts=[], dob=null)
2023-11-13T23:32:28.770+01:00  INFO 19908 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: []
```

As we can see, it has failed to find the account for customer 100.

The repositories look like this:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}

and

public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {}
```

In Grails, two simple annotations would create the required FK and do the joins automatically.

Comment: First, you are using Lombok to generate methods and sets which require rational implementations of Equals and Hashcode to work. Try using a List instead of a Set, and don't use Lombok to generate everything unless you are sure you need it - see the many issues Lombok causes with the Data annotation

Comment: Next, your post has a lot of questions that are mostly answered in the simple OneToMany example you posted. mappedBy = "customer" tells the OneToMany that the fk and all details about the relationship are specified in the Account.customer mapping.

Comment: You are right, Lombok seems to be the issue.  When I get rid of @Data, and manually add getters, setters and a to string, it now does find the account for a given customer, but now it fails because it gets into infinite recursion:  its outputing the json for a customer, and including the list of accounts, but for each account, it incorrectly includes the customer, which includes the account etc.

Comment: Now you are onto JSON serialization, which is a separate topic for your model. You are likely using Spring with Jackson, so you'll need to tell Jackson how to handle your recursive, bidirectional relationships: just as you've told JPA how to handle them. Check out the Ignore, JsonManagedReference, JsonBackReference and JsonIdentityInfo annotations for Jackson and discussion on them (or https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion ). Just using Ignore might cause you problems when deserializing the data into entities as the references will be null

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I'm guessing because you state the inserts work, is that you are not actually adding your Account instances to the Customer.accounts collection when you are persisting data. These are POJOs and JPA maintains caches of these objects, so if you don't maintain both sides of the relationship and keep it in synch with the database, you'll get an empty collection until you refresh the object or restart the application. You don't see the later as a solution because you are recreating the tables all the time.

You can prove this by trying entityManager.refresh(account) on one of the instances and verifying that the state after the call matches what you expect in the database.

To resolve the problem without forcing queries to the database, just makes sure that you add the Account to the customer as well as have the Account reference the Customer.

Comment: Interesting.  What I might do then is create my test data via data.sql, so that jpa/hibernate have to read from DB.

Comment: If you don't understand and fix the issue with persisting test data though, you'll run into it again with real data, as it requires changes in how you handle your entities that aren't always straight forward.

Comment: I pre created the data via SQL scripts, so they would not be cached, then used a controller to read the customer and their accounts, and it finds no accounts still. However, if I get rid of lombok, and add my own getters, setters and to string, it kind of works (but now gives recursion errors)

Answer (score 0):

@Chris was right, it was lombok causing the issues.  It seems you cant use **@Data**, although I have seen examples using it.  However, @Getter and @Setter seem to be ok.

When lombok @Data was removed, I got infinite recursion, even with lazy loading, because returning a Customer object included the Accounts, which included the Customers, which included the Accounts etc.  To fix this I've added **@JsonIgnore** to the Customer filed in Account.

I haven't checked if @ToString works with JPA.
I dont know if I need to implement hashcode or equals.  Equals is a bit moot as all customer accounts are unique (i.e cant have two with same email).

Here is the working code (where different from the original question)

**Account.java**

```
public class Account  {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "account_seq", sequenceName = "account_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "account_seq")
    private Long id;

    BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(0);

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore  // this is required to avoid recursion when returning customer json.
    Customer customer;

    public Account(Customer c) {
        this.customer = c;
    }

    // NOTE: this is not used by the controller to output the json.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", balance=" + balance +
                '}';
    }
}  // end class Account
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "customer_seq", sequenceName = "customer_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "customer_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 64, nullable = true, unique = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 64, nullable = true, unique = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(length = 256, nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 16, message = "Password must be between 8 and 16 characters long")
    private String password;

    private String phone;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private Set<Account> accounts;

    public Customer(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) // not needed any more?
    private Date dob;  // or use sql.Date?

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + dob +
                '}';
    }
} // end class Customer
```

**output to console**

```
2023-11-14T19:14:27.747+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer{id=1, firstName='null', lastName='null', email='user@haha.com', password='haha123', phone='null', dob=null}
2023-11-14T19:14:27.751+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: [Account{id=1, balance=100.00}]
2023-11-14T19:14:27.751+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer{id=2, firstName='null', lastName='null', email='me@foo.com', password='foobarr123', phone='null', dob=null}
2023-11-14T19:14:27.751+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: [Account{id=2, balance=200.00}]
2023-11-14T19:14:27.751+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer{id=100, firstName='bob', lastName='null', email='haha@blabla', password='12345678', phone='null', dob=1969-07-05}
2023-11-14T19:14:27.752+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: [Account{id=100, balance=0.00}]
2023-11-14T19:14:27.752+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : customer: Customer{id=101, firstName='null', lastName='null', email='another@one.com', password='12345678', phone='null', dob=null}
2023-11-14T19:14:27.752+01:00  INFO 97399 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] c.o.bomj.controller.CustomerController   : accounts: []
```

**output of reset endpoint**

```
[{"createdAt":null,"updatedAt":null,"version":null,"id":1,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"email":"user@haha.com","password":"haha123","phone":null,"accounts":[{"id":1,"balance":100.00}],"dob":null},{"createdAt":null,"updatedAt":null,"version":null,"id":2,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"email":"me@foo.com","password":"foobarr123","phone":null,"accounts":[{"id":2,"balance":200.00}],"dob":null},{"createdAt":"2023-11-14T18:14:20.386726Z","updatedAt":"2023-11-14T18:14:20.420915Z","version":1,"id":100,"firstName":"bob","lastName":null,"email":"haha@blabla","password":"12345678","phone":null,"accounts":[{"id":100,"balance":0.00}],"dob":"1969-07-05"},{"createdAt":"2023-11-14T18:14:20.400159Z","updatedAt":"2023-11-14T18:14:20.400166Z","version":0,"id":101,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"email":"another@one.com","password":"12345678","phone":null,"accounts":[],"dob":null}]
```

Comment: That isn't quite necessary - just have to be careful not to have Lombok generate the default toString/hashcode/equals methods for java entities. There are other strategies like listing out the relationships Lombok should exclude from using in those methods, but there is no reason not to let it generate get/set method for you entities (I don't as I hate Lombok and like to have the source as it is for debugging, but its a personal preference).

Comment: Interesting!  do I have to create hashcode/equals methods? I haven't done this yet and it works so far.  The rest responses dont seem to use the toString method I created - Im guessing they are just for your own debug output.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend them unless your app needs them, but that is an opinion others don't share.